# InAppWebView not working inside of a FlutterFragment

Tags: android, flutter, android-fragments, android-webview, flutter-inappwebview

I am attempting to integrate the flutter library [InAppWebView](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/intro) into an existing android App built with traditional XML layout files.
If I use a FlutterActivity then everything seems to work, however if I try to use a FlutterFragment then an error occurs in the inAppWebView.
My goal is to use the WebView inside of a fragment, because I need it to only take up a portion of the screen.

Maybe there is something about the lifecycle of fragments that I have not understood yet. I am hoping that someone can point out something obvious that I am doing wrong.

([Here is a demo project that reproduces the issue](https://github.com/JacobToftgaardRasmussen/FlutterWebViewNotWorkingInFragmentDemo))

1. I have created an Android app and a flutter module.
2. If I load the flutter widget inside of a FlutterActivity then everything works fine
3. If I load the flutter widget inside of a FlutterFragment then the following error occurs:

```
E/OpenGLRenderer: Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled on channel com.pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview_manager)
    #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:308:7)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #1      InAppWebViewController.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled (package:flutter_inappwebview/src/in_app_webview/in_app_webview_controller.dart:3817:12)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #2      main (package:flutter_web_view/main.dart:11:5)
    <asynchronous suspension>
```

This error happens after I attempt to call

```
    await InAppWebViewController.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
```

as one of the first things inside the Future main() function of my main.dart file in the flutter module. (The main.dart file includes the example code from the documentation of the [InAppWebView](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/webview/in-app-webview) library)

4.
If I remove that line to avoid making the call to `setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled` that causes the error then the following error happens instead:

```
E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: com.pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview
        at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:489)
        at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createForPlatformViewLayer(PlatformViewsController.java:163)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:105)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:55)
        at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:258)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8176)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
    , null, null)
    #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
    #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #2      ExpensiveAndroidViewController._sendCreateMessage (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:1040:5)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #3      AndroidViewController.create (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:763:5)
    <asynchronous suspension>
```

5. Either way the webview does not load.
6. I have also opened an [issue](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/1700) on the GitHub Page of the flutter library.

I hope that someone is able to help me out with this.
Thanks a lot in advance, and have a great day!

Comment: did you figure out a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find a solution to this. So I had to come up with a different solution, which did not involve Flutter or InAppWebView.

Answer (score 0):

I used flutter activity instead of flutter fragment and working well now!

Comment: Nice to hear that you found a solution that worked for you. I was unfortunately not able to use an activity instead of a fragment, because I needed the webview to take up only part of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

flutterEngine.platformViewsController.attach(context as Activity, flutterEngine.renderer, flutterEngine.dartExecutor)

That's work for me